# Can I utilise a GPU to accelerate a non graphics related operation in C# such as a parallel for loop?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I have the following CRC calculation that is executed 12 times in parallel on different data sources.

Can I offload this to the GPU once the CPU thread count is exhausted, or is the GPU not suited for such tasks and it does not make sense to do such a calculation on the GPU ?

If this is the wrong place to ask this question, could you please suggest where it should be asked.

```
private static readonly byte[] _crcLookup = new byte[1024];

public static uint CalculateCRC(byte[] data, uint lower, uint upper)
{
    uint offset = 0;
    uint addr = 0;

    var segment = data;

    uint crc = uint.MaxValue;
    addr = lower;
    while (addr <= upper)
    {
        crc = crc >> 8 ^ _crcLookup [(byte)(data[addr] ^ crc)];
        addr++;
    }

    crc = ~crc;
    return crc;
}
```

Parallel implementation

```
var dataSegments = new ConcurrentBag<(byte[] data, uint lower, uint upper)>();

Parallel.ForEach(dataSegments, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }, segment =>
{
    uint result = CalculateCRC(segment.data, segment.lower, segment.upper);
    // Do something with the result...
});
```

Comment: The c# compiler will optimize the code into assembly language automatically.  The compiler knows what code will run use GPU assembly code when needed.  GPU is designed to do large numbers of multiplications.  Your code is using shifts and adds which is better done with the micro shift/add instructions.

Comment: Does the C# JIT really offload to the GPU automatically? Is there any documentation about this? My goal was to use the GPU even if it was slower to simply get better utilisation of an otherwise dormant piece of silicon.

Comment: No it will not. You need to use the appropriate library and use the respective patterns. But if you do, the compiler will produce cpu code and gpu code that is not the same instruction set.

Comment: Consider using built in classes such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.hashing.crc32.hash?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: I wrote a toy project for computations like that with OpenCL: https://github.com/tugrul512bit/Cekirdekler/wiki/Load-Balancing you can use your gpu directly within C# for simple math. Crc computation of yours looks a bit serial like Mandelbrot but if you need it independently for thousands of different data, thousands crc in flight, then it can be parallelized easily just like Mandelbrot set generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I offload this to the GPU once the CPU thread count is exhausted, or is the GPU not suited for such tasks and it does not make sense to do such a calculation on the GPU ?

Technically yes, but only with great difficulty. You cannot run arbitrary c# code on a GPU, so you would likely need to write the GPU code in some other language, with all the complexity that entails.

But chances are you will only see a performance reduction. CRC calculations should be IO limited if the code is decently well optimized. So the extra overhead to transfer data to the GPU would very likely cost more than it could benefit. Also, GPUs are designed for massive parallelism. In the `while (addr <= upper)`-loop you have a dependency between iterations, so it could not directly be parallelized. It *might* be possible to do some hierarchical version of CRC, but even then, the overhead would be prohibitive.

Parallelizing on the 12 different data sources should be done on different threads, not on the GPU. A CPU core is much faster than a "GPU core". You just have single/double digit CPU cores, but possibly thousands of GPU cores.

Answer (score -5):

Here is the code:

```cs
private static readonly byte[] _crcLookup = new byte[1024];

public static uint CalculateCRC(byte[] data, uint lower, uint upper)
{
    uint offset = 0;
    uint addr = 0;

    var segment = data;

    uint crc = uint.MaxValue;
    addr = lower;
    while (addr <= upper)
    {
        crc = crc >> 8 ^ _crcLookup [(byte)(data[addr] ^ crc)];
        addr++;
    }

    crc = ~crc;
    return crc;
}

var dataSegments = new ConcurrentBag<(byte[] data, uint lower, uint upper)>();

Parallel.ForEach(dataSegments, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }, segment =>
{
    uint result = CalculateCRC(segment.data, segment.lower, segment.upper);
    // Do something with the result...
});
```

Using a GPU for non-graphics operations in C# like a CRC calculation might not be straightforward. While there are libraries like CUDA.NET that allow for GPU programming in C#, it's important to note that not all operations benefit from GPU parallelization. In some cases, the overhead of transferring data between CPU and GPU memory can outweigh the benefits gained from parallelization.

Comment: I am failing to see where this is different from OP's code in the question ...